# How to set fit function range to fit the function only between few data points in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a data point between 1-100 and I want to fit the Gaussian function only between data point 30 to 50. So how can I set the fit range 30 - 50 in the python.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what you've already tried.

Comment: I have attached a link of the code and data here please have a look and let me know how I can fit the data only between 160 - 205 range of the data point of X-axis. 1. link for python code https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxgzlvaw7kjh54g/polya_fit.py?dl=0   and  for data file is https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri03xounioy1c9f/QDC1_4500V.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

you can use slice notation

```
l_ = list(range(1, 100))

start = 30
stop = 50
print (l_[start-1:stop])
```

**Slicing Python Lists/Arrays**

```
a[start:stop]  # items start through stop-1
a[start:]      # items start through the rest of the array
a[:stop]       # items from the beginning through stop-1
a[:]           # a copy of the whole array
```

There is also the **step** value, which can be used with any of the above:

```
a[start:stop:step] # start through not past stop, by step
```

The key point to remember is that the :stop value represents the first value that is not in the selected slice. So, the difference between stop and start is the number of elements selected (if step is 1, the default).

The other feature is that start or stop may be a negative number, which means it counts from the end of the array instead of the beginning. So:

```
a[-1]    # last item in the array
a[-2:]   # last two items in the array
a[:-2]   # everything except the last two items
```

Similarly, step may be a negative number:

```
a[::-1]    # all items in the array, reversed
a[1::-1]   # the first two items, reversed
a[:-3:-1]  # the last two items, reversed
a[-3::-1]  # everything except the last two items, reversed
```

Example:

```
l_ = list(range(10)) #  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print (l_)
print (l_[2:5])
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4]
```